# Join of monotonic functions is monotonic

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Given two monotonic functions $F$ and $G$ on a complete lattice, how would I go about proving that the function:

$$ H : x \mapsto F(x) \vee G(x) $$

is monotonic (i.e. $a \leq b \implies H(a) \leq H(b)$)?

Comment: What have you tried? If you show what you have tried, it help someone write an answer appropriate to  what you already know.

Comment: I've written down a few obvious things, e.g. $F(x) \leq H(x)$ and $G(x) \leq H(x)$, and I thought about splitting the proof into cases based on how $F(a)$ and $G(b)$ relate with respect to the ordering (where $a \leq b$), but didn't get very far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a \le b$. Then $F(a)\le F(b) \le F(b) \vee G(b)$ and $G(a) \le G(b)\le F(b) \vee G(b)$. Thus $F(b) \vee G(b)$ is an upper bound of $\{F(a),G(a)\}$. Since $F(a) \vee G(a)$ is the least upper bound of $\{F(a),G(a)\}$ you have
$F(a) \vee G(a) \le F(b) \vee G(b)$.